# How did they manage to bring weapons into the Stock Exchange?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In The Dark Knight Rises, when Bane plans an attack on the stock market, his affiliates manage to infiltrate the lower level workforce.

But how do they manage to take inside their arms without anyone noticing or any alarms beeping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The novelisation indicates that they smuggled the weapons inside innocuous work items, while posing as menial employees

> "In the men’s room, a janitor mopped the floor. Toilets flushed in the background. Crumpled paper towels littered the floor. He paused to peek at his wristwatch. Almost time, he thought. He reached into his bucket and extracted a sealed Ziploc bag. A micro-Uzi machine pistol waited inside the bag. The janitor tossed away his mop"

And

> "The shoeshine man, whose name was McGarrity, put down his brush. A bulging gym bag rested at the foot of the stand. Glancing about, he unzipped the bag and inspected a loaded sub-machine gun. Smuggling the gun into the building had not been easy, but the time for stealth was almost over. He hoisted the bag over his shoulder and trotted after the unsuspecting brokers"

The scenes also appear in the film

[image]

Comment: Im pretty sure it shows this in the film too

Comment: But they were already inside the building. Do they not inspect them at the entrance of the building?

Comment: @mddanishkhan - Evidently security was sufficiently lax as to not check inside a slop bucket or concealed in a bag of metal tools.

Comment: @MdDanishKhan: It's a dirty secret of the security world that most security is theatre.